# Unable to set "element-name" of Accessibility Identifier for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, xcode-ui-testing

1. For UITableViewCell i am using

   ```
   // Set Accessibility Identifiers
   [cell setAccessibilityIdentifier:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld",SETTINGS_MY_PROFILE_CollectionView_Cell,(long)indexPath.row]];
   ```
2. This return's

   ```
   {"element-id":"settings_my_profile_CollectionView_Cell_0", 
   "element-type":"VZIPTVProfileColorSelectorCell"}, 
   {"element-id":"settings_my_profile_CollectionView_Cell_1",
   "element-type":"VZIPTVProfileColorSelectorCell"}
   ```
3. How can i set `"element-name" along with "element-id" & "element-type" for`UITableViewCell`? Any direct for indirect methodology?

Comment: What is `element-name` and why are you trying to set it? Why are you not accessing the cell via `[[XCUIApplication alloc] init].cells[@"settings_my_profile_CollectionView_Cell_0"];`?

Comment: I need tag "element-name" for one logical grouping in SQA-Hooks. For clickable elements like UIButton, i am getting "element-name" as well along with element-id" & element-type using setAccessibilityIdentifier.